# Jquery html5 canvas change color variable

Tags: jquery, canvas

Trying to do something along these lines. Change the color of the canvas object when $this css is .current

```
var links = $("ul#nav-main a");

links.each(function() {
    var linkWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    var canvas = $("<canvas></canvas>");
    canvas.attr({width: linkWidth, height: 48});
    var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    var linkColor = "rgba(27, 73, 218, 0.5)";
    if links.css('.current'){
        linkColor = "red"
    }
    ctx.save();
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(linkWidth, 45.0);
          ctx.lineTo(6.5, 46.3);
          ctx.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
          ctx.lineTo(linkWidth-2, 2.0);
          ctx.lineTo(linkWidth-4, 45.0);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fillStyle('linkColor');
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.restore();

    var image = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    $(this).hover(function() {
                $(this).css({background: "url('"+image+"') no-repeat"});
    }, function() {
    $(this).css({background: ""});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part

```
if links.css('.current'){
    linkColor = "red"
}
```

with

```
if $(this).hasClass('current') {
    linkColor = "#f00";
}
```

where `$(this)` referres to the current element in the `each()` loop as a jQuery object and `hasClass()` returns true if the elements class attribute contains the CSS class.

Not to familiar with the canvas element yet but I also think you should replace `ctx.fillStyle('linkColor');` with `ctx.fillStyle = linkColor;`.

Why are you calling `ctx.save();` before you set the color (and other) and then also `ctx.restore();` once you have?

**UPDATE**

Created a **[solution at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzrnC/)** for you, enjoy! :)

Comment: Hi Stefan many thanks. Im fumbling through this myself, as you can tell:) Im not even sure of the reason for ctx.save / restore

Comment: Updated my answer with a live example of the complete solution. Hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/QzrnC/